# How to set Android home screen grid size to 6x6?

Tags: home-screen

I use a Samsung Galaxy S9+. My home screen grid only allows till 5x6 grid. Is there any way to set customise grid layouts?

Comment: you need to install 3rd party launcher for example nova, cpl, rootless etc. they allow you to customize the home screen (not the samsung's).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using another launcher. [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) for example allows to set 6x6 grid.
After installing, long-press on the home screen, select settings. When the settings open, click Home Screen -> Desktop grid, set it to 6x6.

There are other launchers that can also do it. Just search on your favorite app store.

Comment: I use Nova Launcher, it has many other nice features.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Good Lock](https://apps.samsung.com/appquery/appDetail.as?appId=com.samsung.android.goodlock) from the Galaxy Store.

Then install Home Up in the 'Make Up' section.